# Asynchronous code in SilverLight with SharePoint

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010

I have some problem with my code. I have silverlight button after I press button I want to load document library and get information about how many items are in this library co my code is:

```
 var web = context.Web;
 List sharedDocumentsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("dokumenty");

 int i = sharedDocumentsList.ItemCount;

 context.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
 context.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnFileWriteSucceeded, OnFileWriteFailed);
```

But I got still same problem.

**The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explixitly requested**

How Can I get ItemCount. This is only a simple example I need to work with this list in cycle and so on. But I need to solve this main problem. How to work with this documentlist directly in button click method.

Thank You.

Comment: When I try to make this with 

context.ExecuteQuery();

I got this error: 

"The method or property that is called may block the UI thread and it is not allowed. Please use background thread to invoke the method or property, for example, using System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method to invoke the method or property.

So in my button click method I am not able to make this with 
context.ExecuteQuery();
But also I am unable to get result When I make this Asynchronous. 

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private List docList;
private void GetList()
{
    var context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
    context.Load(context.Web);
    docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("dokumenty");
    context.Load(docList);
    context.ExecuteQueryAsync(GetListSucceded, GetListFailed);
}

private void GetListFailed(object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs e)
{            
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyErrorFunction();
}

private void GetListSucceded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => GetItemsCount());
}

private void GetItemsCount()
{
    MessageBox.Show(docList.ItemCount.ToString());
}
```